# applicationInitialization during azure slot swap with different hostnames

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config, azure-deployment-slots

We are attempting to use the applicationInitialization feature

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization>
        <add initializationPage="/" hostName="[app hostname]" />
        <add initializationPage="/Home/About" hostName="[app hostname]" />
    </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots during a slot swap.
However, our hostnames change during the slot swap.

e.g:

staging slot has the hostname: staging-mysite.com

and the live slot has the hostname: mysite.com

Just wondering if anyone else has come across this scenario or have any recommendations on how to achieve this?

One way to do it could be to manually update the web.config, during the swap?

Cheers

James

Comment: Not sure what's your question. As you could see in that document, hostname would change during a swap. Could you specify what you want do with `web.config`?

Comment: hi @DorisLv, changing the hostname during the swap is exactly what I want to do!
I can't see from the document how it would change the host name?
Could you point out where that is in the document?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

I test with a simple Asp.Net Core Web App on portal. **The `web.config` file would be swapped while swapping the slots.** So you could modify the `hostname` in both of your slots on KUDU site:

```
https://your-prod.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole -> site -> wwwroot -> web.config

https://your-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole -> site -> wwwroot -> web.config
```

[image]